# java throw java.lang.ClassCastException when i cast content from file to my Object

Tags: java

I try to read data from file "sinhvien.dat" then push into array of Student.

My code:

```
private Student[] docFile() {
    Student[] std = null;
    FileInputStream f = null;
    ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
    try {
        f = new FileInputStream("student.dat");
        inStream = new ObjectInputStream(f);

        std = (Student[]) inStream.readObject();// this line throw error

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Class not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Read file");
    } finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            try {
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
        if (f != null) {
            try {
                f.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
    return std;
}
```

Class Student

```
public class Student implements Serializable { private String studName; Student(String name) { this.studName = name; } public Student() { } public String getStudName() { return studName; } public void setStudName(String studName) { this.studName = studName; } @Override public String toString() { return "Student Name :" + studName; } }
```

I don't know how to fix this error. 
sorry for bad english :(

Comment: Well, looks like that file doesn't have a serialized `Student[]`, or at least not as its first object. How did you create that file?

Comment: What exactly is the `ClassCastException`? What did you _write_ to the file? Also note that you do not need to call `close` on each nested stream, it is the contract of `close` that it does this. If you are using Java 7, consider using a try-with-resources block.

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ClassCastException: btvn_l5.Student cannot be cast to [Lbtvn_l5.Student;

Comment: @user3079521 **Never post code in comments**. This is not constructive - you can see yourself that it is illegible. You can edit your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ClassCastException: btvn_l5.Student cannot be cast to [Lbtvn_l5.Student;
```

This means, that you cannot cast a single Student-obect into an array of Student-objects.
I think you serialize a `Student` and try to deserialize a `Student[]`. Th prefix `[L` indicates an array.

Take a look at you serializer.